# 2D mesh generator with geometric primitives

Tags: software, mesh-generation, unstructured-mesh

The **question** is exactly as the title: 
Which 2D (triangular) mesh generator software can be used which has a set of geometric primitives, controlled mesh size and standard output (.vtk or something similar)?

For testing my code I need a **triangular** mesh for a circle and I am looking for the easiest way to do that. E.g., in 3D case for a sphere I am happy to use NETGEN with several lines of code to get meshes with controlled mesh size and standard output format.

Can anyone give me a recommendation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shewchuk's triangle mesh generator produces high quality meshes and is quite
robust. However, the boundary definition is a series of straight lines. So to
produce a sequence of refined meshes over a circle you would also have to refine
the definition of the boundary for each mesh.

Another option is Persson's [distmesh](http://persson.berkeley.edu/distmesh/) triangle mesher,
As shown on this page, only two lines of MATLAB (or Octave) code are required
to mesh a circle

```
fd=@(p) sqrt(sum(p.^2,2))-1;
[p,t]=distmesh2d(fd,@huniform,0.2,[-1,-1;1,1],[]);
```

And the mesh can be refined by changing a single "mesh density" parameter
with no changes to the geometry definition.

You can conveniently use MATLAB to write the coordinate matrix, `p`, and the
connectivity matrix, `t`, in whatever format you choose. And, as I've verified,
it also runs in Octave if you don't have access to MATLAB.

Comment: Thought the same about the Triangle. distmesh seems to be exactly what I need right now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jonathan Shewchuk's *triangle* mesh generator [1]. It has its own file format, but it can be easily translated. If you plan to embed it in another software, it can be also compiled as a library with an easy to use API.
You can also use CGAL [2], a large piece of software with many functionalities (including 2D mesh generation).

[1] https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html

[2] http://www.cgal.org

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I had some experience with Triangle, but somehow I was sure that it is difficult to make a circle there (are you sure it is possible?), I will look more carefully, as well as have a  look at CGAL.